# pass selectAll parameter from click action

Tags: angular, binding

I'm trying to set `selectAll` parameter value through a click function. When the button is clicked, a pop up action dialog is shown. When I click on cancel button, it should get the `selectAll` parameter.

However when debugging it at console, seems that `selectAll` is undefined when passed to `closeDialog()`.I have tried passing selectAll through actiondialog

```
<action-dialog (cancelAction)="closeDialog(selectAll)" [(selection)]="selectAll"/>
```

However `<action-dialog>` is a component which doesn't allow extra binding parameters.

Would appreciate if somebody had an idea. Thanks!

#### a.html:

```
        <button  (click)="openDialog(); selectAll=false"
                </button>
        <button  (click)="opensecondDialog(); selectAll=true"
                </button>
        <action-dialog (cancelAction)="closeDialog(selectAll)"/>
        <p *ngIf="!selectAll" abc</p>
        <p *ngIf="selectAll" 123 </p>
```

#### a.ts:

```
         closeDialog(selectAll) { 
            if(selectAll) this.clearAlerts();
         }
```

Comment: did you define initial value for selectAll in a.ts?

Comment: yes have defined the initial value

Comment: please show the ts code for `action-dialog`